# screen freeze audio loop watching YouTube on Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox, freeze, youtube

here are my specs :

- OS : Ubuntu 22.04.4 lts, 64bit
- Hardware model : BIOSTAR Group A960D+v2
- memory : DDR3 8gb 800Mhz
- processor: AMD FX 6100 six cores
- graphics: NV137
- graphics card : Nvidia GTX 1050
- kernel version : 6.5.0-25-generic

Hello !

I'm having an issue, it's recent, I installed Ubuntu on my SSD three days ago because my HDD on which I had windows died.

the issue :

i would watch youtube on firefox, and for some reason, about 10 minutes in, I hear in my headset a sort of scratching sound, then the audio loops over the last second, and the screen is frozen, as in mouse, keyboard etc don't seem to work anymore. after a reboot it works fine.

the last things I downloaded were : TOR,  Spotify, DaVinciResolve. I'm new to Ubuntu, and not really familiar with much in computers.

Thank you for your time reading this, and I hope you have a good day. it isn't urgent.

Comment: maybe there is some advice for you [in this Mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/979557)

Comment: I haven't found any solution there, thanks though !

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be fixed. I simply updated firefox :')

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343780)